# How to recovery dataSource after disposed from a catchError

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have one UITableView populated by reactive viewmodel using RxSwift, pagination and refresh are working well. The viewModel.dataSource() is consuming my API and sometime I can receive a empty result parsed as error type.

I want to catch this error and create an empty state, hiding tableview and showing a emptyViewState. I thought I could make it with the catchError.

My problem is after catchError, the dataSource is disposed and I couldn't be able to recovery the empty state and repopulated the tableview, I tried to recreate the dataSource calling self.bindDataSource() but I getting fatal error.

There is a way to avoid dataSource disposed ? How can I reconnect / rebuild the dataSource to recovery from the empty state ?

```
class MyViewControl: UIViewController {

    fileprivate let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    fileprivate let viewModel = ViewModel()
    let dataSource = SearchViewModel.SearchDataSource()

    @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var emptyStateView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // When I disable tableview, can see a hidden view with empty state message and one button
        viewModel.isTableViewHidden
        .bindTo(tableView.rx.isHidden)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
        self.setupTableView()
    }

    fun setupTableView() {
        // ... setup table view
        self.bindDataSource()
    }
    fileprivate func bindDataSource() {
    // Bind dataSource from search to UITableView
        viewModel.dataSource()
            .debug("[DEBUG] Loading Search Tableview ")
            .bindTo( tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource) )
            .addDisposableTo( disposeBag )
    }

    @IBAction fileprivate func emptyStateAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Do something and try to recreate the bindDataSource
        self.bindDataSource()
    }
}

class SearchViewModel {
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    typealias SearchDataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<PaginationStatus<WorkerEntity>>

    let isTableViewHidden = BehaviorSubject<Bool>(value: false)

    // Controls to refresh and paging tableview
    let refreshTrigger  = BehaviorSubject<Void>(value:())
    let nextPageTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()

    // Others things happing herer

    func dataSource() -> Observable<[PaginationStatus<WorkerEntity>]> {
        return self.refreshTrigger.debug("[DEBUG] Refreshing dataSource")
        .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] _ -> Observable<[PaginationStatus<WorkerEntity>]> in 
            // Access the API and return dataSource
        }
        .catchError { [unowned self] error -> Observable<[PaginationStatus<WorkerEntity>]> in
            // Hidden the tableview
            self.isTableViewHidden.onNext(true)
            // Do others things
            return Observable.of([PaginationStatus.sectionEmpty])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you bindDataSource() you dont reinitialised your datasource, so you bind it to a error event. 
You need to init it, to bind it again. And you might want to remove your binding too

let disposeBagTableView = DisposeBag()

```
//remove
let dataSource = SearchViewModel.SearchDataSource()


fileprivate func bindDataSource() {
    // Bind dataSource from search to UITableView
        disposeBagTableView = DisposeBag()
        SearchViewModel.SearchDataSource()
            .debug("[DEBUG] Loading Search Tableview ")
            .bindTo( tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource) )
            .addDisposableTo( disposeBagTableView )
    }
```